# pyqt5.qtcore and pyqt4.qtcore modules both wrap the qobject class

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyuic

I developed a GUI application using `qtcreator` and converted to python script using `pyuic5`.

```
pyuic5 -x app.ui -o app.py
```

Then I imported the main ui as

```
from app import Ui_Rplatform as rp
```

Then I got error on the import line

```
from app import Ui_Rplatform as rp
```

as

```
pyqt5.qtcore and pyqt4.qtcore modules both wrap the qobject class
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: what version of pyqt do you use?

Comment: I used qtcreator. I have both pyqt4 and pyqt5 at the time I developed. Then I deleted pyqt4. But the ui application still working even after pyqt4 was deleted.